# Do not reset value in select drop down on event of reset button click

Tags: javascript, html

I navigate to a page after successful completion of a webservice call and will populate values retrieved from webservice in to input fields of a page and will disable those fields after population.

Now, On click of reset, these values should not be cleared. I am successful in implementing this functionality for input fields by using defaultValue concept.

for e.g. During population of values in to form, I use
    `inputField.defaultValue = inputField.value`

and On click of reset button

```
inputField.value = inputField.defaultValue;
```

to keep the values from clearing..

However, I am not able to achieve the same with select drop down. Its value is getting cleared upon reset button. How to achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: I would expect the same thing to work for select elements, but if you're having trouble...maybe it would be easier to prevent the default reset event, and instead implement your own that only clears fields that don't have a certain class or something - at least that would save having to reference the fields individually in two places in your JS (indeed they wouldn't be referenced individually at all in the JS, just by class).

Comment: @nnnnnn - Thanks for your reply. I have other fields which need to be reset on reset click. Only fields that i populate with web service response data should not get reset.

Comment: Yes, and my suggestion covered that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below one worked for me. Thank you for all who responded -

```
inputField.value = inputField.options[inputField.selectedIndex].value;
inputField.defaultValue = inputField.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of the selection box work different than text boxes. You need to grab the selected values index and then need to use the following code to reset it.

```
document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex = saved_index
```

Hope this will work for you.